# Unable to inject request scoped bean in spring

Tags: java, spring

So I have this bean for database management. I define it in the following way:

```
<bean id="dbmanager" class="rpg.commons.database.DBManager" scope="request"/>
```

Then I try to put it into the controller

```
@Controller
public abstract class AbstractController {

@EJB
protected DBManager dbmanager;

    ...
}
```

I also tried the @Autowired, but in each case, when I try to deploy it on my glassfish server I get the following exception

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'homePageController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected rpg.commons.database.DBManager rpg.web.controllers.AbstractController.dbmanager; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

homePageController is a simple controller that inherits my AbstractController.
I also tried to change the field to public, but it didn't change anything...

Comment: you have to use `aop:scoped-proxy` or `@ScopedProxy` check this [link](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection) from spring refrence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not inject  a request scoped bean into a sigleton directly, Inject a request scoped proxy instead:

```
<bean id="dbmanager" class="rpg.commons.database.DBManager" scope="request">
  <aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>
```

See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection

Answer (score 1):

@EJB is an annotation used to inject, what you'd expect... EJBs. Since your bean is not an EJB that's of course not going to work. Below are two ways of handling dependency injection with Spring:

### Injection via xml

```
<bean id="dbmanager" class="rpg.commons.database.DBManager" scope="request"/>
<bean id="abstractController" class="rpg.commons.database.AbstractController">
    <property name="dbmanager" ref="dbmanager" />
</bean>
```

### Injection via annotations

Spring has its `@Autowired` annotation for handling dependency injections, but you need to 'turn on' annotation scanning in your xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="rpg.commons.database" />
```

and then the below construct will work:

```
@Autowired
protected DBManager dbmanager;
```